# 100% CPU usage with Android Studio and McAfee after upgrade

Tags: android, android-emulator, mcafee

I have upgraded Android Studio to 3.1.2.
When starting any Android Emulator (i.e. qemu-system-i386.exe), my CPU
usage reaches 100%.

Update (5/1/2018):
Actually everything in Android Studio is SLOW after upgrade and I did not change anything in my project (i.e. same settings, same code, same libraries).
Performance was NOT a problem before upgrade.

As per Task Manager, the issue seems to be caused by the antivirus processes (McAfee):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Android Emulator reads very large files. McAfee scans every file that gets opened. So, I'm not surprised by this result.

Unfortunately, the only solutions I know of are to turn off McAfee or exclude the Android\Sdk directories from the on-access scan. If you're in a corporate environment, you may not have access to do either, and so will have to beg IT Security to do it.

Comment: Thank you. Please note that this was not a problem before upgrade. Everything is super slow after upgrade and I did not change anything in my project (i.e. same settings, same code, same libraries).

Comment: Well that's a good point. Maybe the old version was excluded from McAfee and the new one (different directory) is not?